# Scala: How to add match vals to a list val

Tags: scala

I have a few vals that `match` for matching values

Here is an example:

```
 val job_ = Try(jobId.toInt) match {
      case Success(value) => jobs.findById(value).map(_.id)
        .getOrElse( Left(WrongValue("jobId", s"$value is not a valid job id")))
      case Failure(_) => jobs.findByName(jobId.toString).map(_.id)
        .getOrElse( Left(WrongValue("jobId", s"'$jobId' is not a known job title.")))
    }
```

*// Here the value arrives as a string e.i "yes || no || true || or false" then converted to a boolean*

```
val bool_ = bool.toLowerCase() match {
  case "yes" => true
  case "no" => false
  case "true" => true
  case "false" => false
  case other =>  Left(Invalid("bool", s"wrong value received"))
}
```

*Note: invalid case is `case class Invalid(x: String, xx: String)`*

above i'm looking for a given job value and checking whether it exist in the db or not,

No I have a few of these and want to add to a list, here is my list val and flatten it:

```
val errors = List(..all my vals errors...).flatten // <--- my_list_val (how do I include val bool_ and val job_)

if (errors.isEmpty) { do stuff }
```

My result should contain errors from `val bool_` and `val job_`

THANK!

Comment: Could you write down an example to clarify what is your expected outptut ? Thanks

Comment: What type does `WrongValue()` return?

Comment: @SimonDelecourt the output should be val errors (wrong value received, 99 is not a known job title.)

Comment: @jwvh its returns string WrongValue(x: String, xx: String)

Comment: Ah, so `job_` is _supposed_ to be type `Either[String,ID]` (whatever the `.id` type is), and `bool_` is _supposed_ to be type `Either[Invalid,Boolean]`, and you want to combine them into a `List[Either[??,??]]`? Those types look rather incompatible.

Comment: @jwvh yes, correct,  my end result would be something along  -----  val errors = List( bool_.left.toOption).flatten println(s"Errors are: ${errors}")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, according to your question, and your comments, these are the types you're dealing with.

```
type ID = Long //whatever id is
def WrongValue(x: String, xx: String) :String = "?-?-?"
case class Invalid(x: String, xx: String)
```

Now let's create a couple of error values.

```
val job_  :Either[String,ID]       = Left(WrongValue("x","xx"))
val bool_ :Either[Invalid,Boolean] = Left(Invalid("x","xx"))
```

To combine and report them you might do something like this.

```
val errors :List[String] =
  List(job_, bool_).flatMap(_.swap.toOption.map(_.toString))

println(errors.mkString(" & "))
//?-?-? & Invalid(x,xx)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the types first. The type of `bool_` is `Any`. Which does not give you something you can work with.

If you want to use `Either`, you need to use it everwhere.

Then, the easiest approach would be to use a for comprehension (I am assuming you're dealing with `Either[F, T]` here, where `WrongValue` and `Invalid` are both sub-classes of `F` and you're not really interested in the errors).

```
for {
  foundJob <- job_
  _ <- bool_
} yield {
  // do stuff
}
```

---

Note, that in Scala >= 2.13 you can use `toIntOption` when converting the String to Int:

```
vaj job_: Either[F, T] = jobId.toIntOption match {
  case Some(value) =>  ...
  case _ => ...
}
```

Also, in case expressions, you can use alternatives when you have the same statement for several cases:

```
val bool_: Either[F, Boolean] = bool.toLowerCase() match {
  case "yes" | "true"  => Right(true)
  case "no"  | "false" => Right(false)
  case other =>  Left(Invalid("bool", "wrong value received"))
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response - much appreciated, however Ive done what you've suggested and don'y have any issue that far.. my question was how do i add my val to ---- val errors = List(..my_vals_goes_here...).flatten thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After checking types as @cbley explained. You can just do a **filter operation with pattern matching** on your list:

```
val error = List(// your variables ).filter(_ match{
  case Left(_) => true
  case _ => false
})
```

Comment: Probably better would be to use `collect` to filter on `Left` and extract the errors at the same time.